# Edit the animation from onGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter

So basically i try the onGenerateRoute on my flutter apps. and i see some animation, i try look around to change the animation ( any type of animation would be ok )

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title HERE',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 0),
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}

class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage(title: 1));
      case '/screen2':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new Reader(title: settings.arguments);
          },
        );

      case '/screen3':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Info(title: settings.arguments));
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
                ));
    }
  }
}
```

to push the data i use

```
 onTap: () =>
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screen2', arguments: <String, String>{
              'name': name,
              'title': title,
            }),
```

any type of animation would be good ( slide left, slide right ) so i can play around with it.

IMO maybe the solution is using the PageRouteBuilder , but I'm still figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

please use PageRouteBuilder 
full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              return SlideRightRoute(widget:HomePage());
              break;
            case '/second':
              return SlideRightRoute(widget:SecondHome());
              break;
          }
        }
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
          },
          child: Text('Second Home'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class SecondHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SlideRightRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget widget;
  SlideRightRoute({this.widget})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      return widget;
    },
    transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child) {
      return new SlideTransition(
        position: new Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
          end: Offset.zero,
        ).animate(animation),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

[image]